# Container Div Won't Appear

Tags: html, css

My page has a layout with a top, middle and bottom section (they are all divs.) So far I have only been able to get the top and bottom areas to appear correctly. Even though the content of the middle is exactly the same as the bottom it just wont appear, therefore I am assuming a simple and obvious syntax era has most likely occurred, the thing is I have spent hour reading and troubleshooting to no avail, so please help!

Here is my HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Saspadidious</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\home.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="home.html">
        <div id="top">
            <h1 class="header9">Sarspadidious</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="middle">
        <div class="subOrange">
            <h1 class="header6">Who?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subOrange">
            <h1 class="header6">What?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="subOrange">
            <h1 class="header6">Why?</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <div class="subRed">
            <a href="software.html">
                <h1 class="header4">Software</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="subRed">
            <a href="support.html">
                <h1 class="header4">Support</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="subRed">
            <a href="about.html">
                <h1 class="header4">About</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="subRed">
            <a href="news.html">
                <h1 class="header4">News</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image:url('../Images/arches.PNG');
font-size:100%;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:rgb(44,44,44);
}

@font-face {
font-family:"Mission Script";
src:url('../Other/Mission-Script.OTF');
}

#top {
position:relative;
width:90%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top:5%;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:3%;
background-color:rgb(197,129,84);
border-color:rgb(44,44,44);
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
}

#middle {
position:relative;
width:95%;
margin-top:5%;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
}

#bottom {
position:relative;
width:95%;
margin-top:5%;
margin-bottom:5%;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
}

.subOrange {
position:relative;
width:26.6%;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
padding-top:3%;
padding-bottom:3%;
background-color:rgb(255,159,72);
border-color:rgb(44,44,44);
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
float:left;
}

.subRed {
position:relative;
width:18.75%;
margin-left:2.5%;
margin-right:2.5%;
padding-top:3%;
padding-bottom:3%;
background-color:rgb(255,69,70);
border-color:rgb(44,44,44);
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:15px;
float:left;
}

.header4 {
font-family:"Mission Script";
font-size:4em;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
color:rgb(44,44,44);
}

.header6 {
font-family:"Mission Script";
font-size:6em;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
color:rgb(44,44,44);
}

.header9 {
font-family:"Mission Script";
font-size:9em;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:rgb(44,44,44);
}
```

So there it all is, the text in the middle div also does not display correctly, it does not become the right size or use Mission Script as its font.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of what my browser does when it renders it.

[image: Chrome Linux (Ububtu 10.04)]

[image: Safari Mac OSX (Dunno what version I hate my iMac)]

Comment: This works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using chrome for Linux, but it also didn't work on Chrome for Windows.

Comment: Works for me (Windows) on Firefox 18, Opera 12.00, Chromium 24.0.1311.0, and even Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out! Yes the problem was simple. The page that has the problem in question is an about page, (about.html.)

During it's creation I copied and pasted much of it's code from the home page, (home.html.) What I forgot to do was link it to the new CSS sheet I created for it (about.css) as you can see in my original code above it is still linked to home.css.

I knew it was going to be obvious! THE RELIEF IS UNCANNY!

Here is the problem in code...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\home.css">
```

Change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\about.css">
```

Thanks everyone, sorry for wasting your expertise on such an obvious error. Bloody hell.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on chrome for windows as well. However it fails the w3c validation for the doctype specified in your html either way, id start here http://validator.w3.org/ and make sure your markup matches the doctype you're going for.

For a start, you'll need to change this:

```
<a href="home.html">

    <div id="top">
        <h1 class="header9">Sarspadidious</h1>
    </div>

</a>
```

to this:

```
<div id="top">
    <h1 class="header9"><a href="home.html">Sarspadidious</a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I wonder why it does not work in linux then, I will try on my imac.

Comment: AFAIK, `<a><div></div></a>` is valid HTML 5, though definitely not HTML 4.01, and it's not supported in most browsers. Developing on HTML 4.01 doesn't tend to work out well if you want to use today's web technology, like CSS3.

Comment: Actually, the preferred solution here is removing the `<div>` entirely, in favor of `<a id="top" style="display:block;" href="home.html">` or the like.

Comment: I have just removed the divs in favour of what Tortoise has recommened, still not displaying the orange ones though, not even their font is displayed correctly.